# How do I display the product Long Description in the product review page?

Tags: php, magento

I have a layout that requires the product description on the reviews page.  How can I accomplish this?

Magento version is 1.6

It appears as though the Review page is loading the Product View template just without some of the information; from product/view.phtml:

```
<div id="product-details">
    <?php foreach ($this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml') as $alias => $html):?>
            <div class="box-collateral <?php echo "box-{$alias}"?>">
                <?php echo $html; ?>
            </div>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</div>
```

and on the main product view it shows the details here, but on the review view it does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What version of Magento?  How is the product collection loaded?

You will need to customize one of the templates location in the below, make sure to move into your template and do not edit the base files.

/var/www/vhosts/site.com/www/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/review/

```
<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getDescription(), 'description') ?>
```

Is how this is loaded on a standard product view.

You may have to set the $_product variable via `<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>` and `<?php $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output'); ?>`

Comment: `code`
<div id="product-details">
 <?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
 <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getDescription(), 'description') ?>
</div>
`code`
ended up working thanks!